# How to add smooth Scrolling to single anchor instead of whole page

Tags: javascript, html, css, anchor-scroll

I have created 2 anchors within my page
As of default , whenever one clicks on anchor link ,it directly jumps to the requested section

One easy way of  enabling smooth Scrolling is adding this in CSS file but it affects the whole html page , I don't want that

i want this smooth Scrolling property to only apply to a single anchor within my page ( lets say the section 1 anchor for this example ) and not every anchors universally

Html Codes are included below in snippets

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<a href="#Section1">Section 1</a><br>
<a href="#Section2">Section 2</a>

<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>

<a class="anchor" id="Section1">&nbsp;</a>

<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>

<a class="anchor2" id="Section2">&nbsp;</a>
```

Comment: I like the problem, but I doubt is is sovable with CSS alone

Comment: Although  I am not familiar with JavaScript , its fine if its included in answer because most probably the Javascript dealing with this would hardly be 6,7 lines   so not a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution using (Vanilla) JavaScript.

I just toggles the `className` of the `<html>` element dependent on the `data-smooth-scroll` attribute being set on the link.

```js
"use strict";

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var className = 'smooth';
  var classList = document.documentElement.classList;
  if (e.target.dataset.smoothScroll) {
    classList.add(className)
  } else {
    classList.remove(className)
  }
})
```

```css
html.smooth {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

section {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid gold;
  margin: 50px auto;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<a href="#Section1">Section 1</a><br>
<a href="#Section2">Section 2</a>
<a href="#Section3" data-smooth-scroll="1">Section 3</a>

<a class="anchor" id="Section1">&nbsp;</a>
<section>
  <h2>Section 2</h2>
</section>

<a class="anchor" id="Section2">&nbsp;</a>
<section>
  <h2>Section 2</h2>
</section>

<a class="anchor" id="Section3">&nbsp;</a>
<section>
  <h2>Section 3</h2>
</section>
```

If you don't want the link to decide whether to smooth-scroll or not but the target anchor instead, this should work

```js
"use strict";

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var className = 'smooth';
  var classList = document.documentElement.classList;
  classList.remove(className)
  if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
    var id = e.target.hash.replace(/^#/, '')
    var anchor = document.getElementById(id);
    
    if (anchor && anchor.dataset.smoothScroll) {
      classList.add(className)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
html.smooth {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

section {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid gold;
  margin: 50px auto;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<a href="#Section1">Section 1</a><br>
<a href="#Section2">Section 2</a>
<a href="#Section3">Section 3</a>

<a class="anchor" id="Section1">&nbsp;</a>
<section>
  <h2>Section 2</h2>
</section>

<a class="anchor" id="Section2" data-smooth-scroll="1">&nbsp;</a>
<section>
  <h2>Section 2</h2>
</section>

<a class="anchor" id="Section3">&nbsp;</a>
<section>
  <h2>Section 3</h2>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Add Smooth Scrolling to the Link Name field.
- Select Before Body End Tag from the Placement menu.
- Paste the script below into the blank    field.

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
      jQuery(function($) {

        // The speed of the scroll in milliseconds
        var speed = 1000;

        // Find links that are #anchors and scroll to them
        $('a[href^=#]')
          .not('.lp-pom-form .lp-pom-button')
          .unbind('click.smoothScroll')
          .bind('click.smoothScroll', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top }, speed);
          });
      });
    </script>
```

- Click the Save Code button in the bottom right corner of the dialog
  box.

Comment: Tried it but doesn't seem to work.    You can please send a jsfiddle or something showing the output